# Can an ASN.1 DER SET have multiple entries of same key?

Tags: asn.1, der

I have the following Definition:

```
PersonalName ::= SET {
   surname     [0] IMPLICIT PrintableString
                    (SIZE (1..ub-surname-length)),
   given-name  [1] IMPLICIT PrintableString
                    (SIZE (1..ub-given-name-length)) OPTIONAL,
   initials    [2] IMPLICIT PrintableString
                    (SIZE (1..ub-initials-length)) OPTIONAL,
   generation-qualifier [3] IMPLICIT PrintableString
                    (SIZE (1..ub-generation-qualifier-length))
                    OPTIONAL }
```

Is it allowed to have e.g. two times surname encoded with this definition?

Comment: No, you can't have multiple given provided schema. Only one instance of `surname` is permitted in your SET.

Comment: As per Crypt32 has said, with the added point that malformed data featuring a repeated field might rightly be treated as suspect and possibly hazardous! The whole point of a the definition is to agree an interface, so if you need to send two surnames change the definition to support that (e.g. surname becomes a IMPLICIT SEQUENCE (SIZE(2)) OF PrintableString (SIZE(1..sdfsdf)) ). Interestingly, Google Protocol Buffers doesn't care; if you send it repeated fields, it deserialises them all and the resultant object contains only the last one. I've never liked that.

Comment: or IMPLICITY SEQUENCE (SIZE(1..2)) of PrintableString (SIZE(1..sdfsfd))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in section 3.8.72 (definition of set types) in the T-REC-X680 specification:

> 3.8.72 set types: Types defined by referencing a fixed, unordered, list of types (some of which may be declared to be optional); each
> value in the set type is an unordered list of values, **one from each**
> **component type.**
>
> NOTE – Where a component type is declared to be
> optional, a value of the set type need not contain a value of that
> component type.

Your BER or DER encoded files contains values and the above clause defines that the value which is of the "set type" shall contain one value for each component type of the set (except for optional components, which according to the Note, can be omitted).